# Solr filter for dots/periods unless it starts with some phrase

Tags: regex, solr, lucene

I'm wondering how I can replace periods [`.`] while indexing data into solr.

*Except*, I want to keep words that begin with certain phrases as whole tokens.

For example,

`word.phrase` should be indexed as two keywords: `word`, `phrase`

But, I want anything prefixed with `item.` to not be split by periods, so that:

`item.name` should be indexed as one keyword: `item.name`

I'm trying these filters/tokenizers but still no luck, and I think my regex is the culprit:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
            pattern="[^(item)]\." replacement=" " />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: If it is a Lucene regex engine behind the scenes, try `@&~(item\.+)` (it matches any string but a string starting with `item`). It won't work in your replacement, you might use it to filter out non-qualifying strings. There must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

In order to match "foo" only when it's not preceded by "bar", your regular expression needs a [negative lookbehind assertion](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

The following regex matches dots that are not preceded by "item" : `(?<!\bitem)\.`.
In schema.xml the pattern must be xml escaped to be parsed correctly, so `<` becomes `&lt;`:

```
pattern="(?&lt;!\bitem)\."
```

As an alternative, you could use a *filter* (placed *after* the tokenizer) instead of a charfilter.